# Facebook OG:image tags reporting wrong size

Tags: facebook-opengraph

in this page for instance: 
https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.diveboard.com%2Fdennis.arreborg%2FD5wJDrE

I have the og:image tag pointing to http://st2.diveboard.com/222/25135_daa7a025d22d2acb8102d6ca8ddb284f_large.jpeg

which is :

dentify 25135_daa7a025d22d2acb8102d6ca8ddb284f_large.jpeg
25135_daa7a025d22d2acb8102d6ca8ddb284f_large.jpeg JPEG **1279x799** 1279x799+0+0 8-bit DirectClass 228KB 0.000u 0:00.000

Yet on Facebook debug I get a strange error message :

```
og:image should be larger:  
Provided og:image is not big enough. Please use an image that's at least 200x200 px. Image     'http://st5.diveboard.com/222/22562_8e364ce284eaa3ecb3f8ab5c84789310_large.jpeg' will be used instead.
```

any clue ?

Answer (score 0):

I did a Facebook share on http://www.diveboard.com/dennis.arreborg/D5wJDrE and it correctly used image http://st5.diveboard.com/222/22562_8e364ce284eaa3ecb3f8ab5c84789310_large.jpeg. So no image size problem there.

I encountered situations with my own website in which images were not given as options to include in the share, although they met the size requirments: picture must be at least 50px by 50px (though minimum 200px by 200px is preferred) and have a maximum aspect ratio of 3:1. Just trying to share again solved the problem, and I read somewhere in the Facebook docs that you need to give Facebook 24 hours to somehow update itself for new images on your site.

I would love to give you references to the corresponding Facebook docs, but can't find it back, because they are being changed all the time, I guess.